# Nesting Identifying Relationships / Composite Primary Keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent

I am trying to solve a problem with nesting one->many identifying relationships using composite primary keys to achieve this. I have the following code which works as expected:

```
public class Parent 
{
     public virtual ICollection<UnnamedLocation> UnnamedLocations { get; set; }
}

public class UnnamedLocation : Location {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UnnamedLocationID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And the identifying relationship established with the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UnnamedLocation>()
            .HasKey(m => new {m.UnnamedLocationID, m.ParentID})
```

The problem is I want to add a collection of coordinates to the 'UnnamedLocation' object:

```
public virtual ICollection<Coordinate> Coordinates {get; set;}
```

I would then plan to add the same type of identifying relationship so that EF will properly handle orphaned records:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Coordinate>()
            .HasKey(m => new {m.CoordinateID, m.UnnamedLocationID})
```

The problem is (as I think I understand it) EF now sees the PK of the `UnnamedLocation` as being the combination of `UnnamedLocationID` and `ParentID` and will throw an exception like the following:

**The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.**

Comment: Someone else somewhere must have done this, or there is a glaring design issue I am missing...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define nested Identifying Relationships Entity Framework code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033934/how-to-define-nested-identifying-relationships-entity-framework-code-first)