# Entity Framework 7: Identifying relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

In previous versions of EF I can use following code to implement an identifying relationship:

```
public class Child
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public virtual int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

It's needed to easily remove a child from collection like this:

```
var parent = _context.Parents.First();
var child = parent.Children.First();

parent.Children.Remove(child);

_context.SaveChanges();
```

This approach is described in http://www.kianryan.co.uk/2013/03/orphaned-child/ (the method #2).

But in EF7 this code throws exception when migration is creating:

> An exception was thrown while executing a resolve operation. See the
>   InnerException for details. ---> Entity type 'Child' has composite
>   primary key defined with data annotations. To set composite primary
>   key, use fluent API.

I also tried to use FluentAPI as described in [How to define nested Identifying Relationships Entity Framework code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033934/how-to-define-nested-identifying-relationships-entity-framework-code-first) in following code:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Children)
            .WithOne(c => c.Parent);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
            .HasKey(c => new {c.Id, c.ParentId});

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

This approach allow generate a migration successfully, but when I tried to remove a child from `Children` collection I got following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The association between entity types
>   'Parent' and 'Child' has been severed but the foreign key for this
>   relationship cannot be set to null. If the dependent entity should be
>   deleted, then setup the relationship to use cascade deletes.

But I wouldn't like to use cascade deletes, I would like to use identifying relationship!

Please, help me understand what I do incorrect. Thank you!

Comment: You want to delete the child completely?  Or you want to remove just the parent-child relationship?

Comment: @MihailStancescu, yes, I would like to delete both relationship and child.

Comment: The you should configure cascade deletes as the error message says. Or you have to manually remove the child which is what you didn't want in the first place.

Comment: @MihailStancescu I tried it and it works fine. It seems I have understand how it works... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use cascade on delete instead as this is what it's used for:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Children)
    .WithOne(c => c.Parent);
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591620.aspx

Comment: You should not have to have cascade deletes turned on for this.  Cascade deletes are for deleting children when the *parent of the relationship is deleted*, NOT for deleting the child when it's removed from a collection -- that's what setting the identifying relation is supposed to be for (i.e. using a composite primary key of the row id and foreign key), and that's how it worked in EF 6.  Maybe things have changed in EF 7, but if so, this still isn't a good idea, because it's not always possible to turn on cascade deletes if it creates a circular chain of events.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone sees this error, let me tell you how I resolved mine:

When you do an update, on EF you need to first query the database and get the data model, then map the Domain layer model with your changes onto it (basically copying fields onto the data), and finally call the DBContext update method, then save changes.

My problem was that my model (not the data model, the domain model) also had the sub objects on it.

So here's the data layer model (for example):

```
public class Parent
{
   public int ChildId {get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("ChildId")]
   public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
}
```

And here's how the domain layer model should be:

```
public class Parent
    {
        public int ChildId { get; set; }
        //public Child Child { get; set; }  // this caused the error, keep reading if you want to know more.
    }
```

When I was seeing the error, I had been using Autofac's runtime mapper to map the domain layer model's properties onto the data layer model.  However, the child in the domain layer model was null, so it would nullify the data layer, causing the error:

"The association between entity types 'Parent' and 'Child' has been severed but the foreign key for this relationship cannot be set to null.  If the dependent entity should be deleted, then setup the relationship to use cascade deletes."

---

By the way, in the db context class, I have the following relationship defined:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
   .HasOne(a => a.Child)
   .WithMany()
   .HasForeignKey(p => p.ChildId)
   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

It's working.

Comment: This does create orphans if the parent is deleted, but just in case you want that kind of behavior for some reason, this is how to do it.